# Is there a problem of reusing hoshanos?

Tags: minhag, hoshana-rabbah

On hoshana rabbah we bang aravos on the ground.

Can one use hoshanos that one banged on the floor already or does one need his own?

Comment: Do you mean reusing *arovos*?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I believe that's what Sam means. Many people refer to the bundle as "hoshanos".  I received an email from a local Shteibel today seeking "a volunteer to pick up Hoshanos".

Answer (score 4):

[Nitei Gavriel Succah 79:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46442&st=&pgnum=378) says that it is proper not to reuse an Arava that was used already, however there is no problem Halachically.

Kovetz Halachos from Rabbi Shmuel Kamenetzky says that it is Mutar L'Chatchila to reuse so long as there are leaves remaining on the Arava.

Comment: If there "is no problem Halachically", does he indicate why it is not proper to do so?